# if... else if javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, if-statement

I am doing a form validation and having troubles with my code:

```
var reValue = /^\s*$/;      
var phoneClass = /(^|\s)phoneValidate(\s|$)/;              
var phoneValue = 
     /^[01]?[- .]?(\([2-9]\d{2}\)|[2-9]\d{2})[- .]?\d{3}[- .]?\d{4}$/;  

for (var i=0; i < iLen; i++) {
    el = allElements[i];

    if(phoneClass.test(el.className) && reValue.test(el.value)){
        // The field is empty.
        aMessages += 'Please enter a phone number in: '+ el.name +'.\n';
    }
    else if (phoneClass.test(el.className) && phoneValue.test(el.value)) {
        // The field is not a valid phone number
        // Advise user to fix it
        aMessages += 'Please enter a valid phone number in: '+ el.name +'.\n';
    }
}
```

The first IF statement works and displays the massage if the field is empty, but the ELSE IF for some reason does not...
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: there is 'reValue', 'phoneValue' and 'phoneClass'...

Comment: You just need to *massage* your code a bit (sorry about that, couldn't resist!)

Comment: @DavidWolever How does that comment even suit in this case...? The OP has created a SSCE, and phrased a clear question. What else can he do before posting the question?

Comment: @bfavaretto :) stupid auto-correct ...

Comment: @RobW you are right. Radi, please forgive me for taking out my unrelated frustrations on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on looking at your regex, I think you need to invert the logic on the `phoneValue` test.  You want the `else if` clause to execute when it does NOT match the `phoneValue` regex like this:

```
else if (phoneClass.test(el.className) && !phoneValue.test(el.value)) {
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! I have been banging my head against the wall for the past 2-3 hours not knowing what is going on... Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

`phoneValue.test(el.value)` resolves to `false`. That is why the `else if` is not firing.